# Admob: Ad serving is disabled, but neither PIN nor PIN card are available

Tags: admob

I use Admob in my iOS apps.

I am facing the following issue:

On my Home page at **admob.com**, there is a card saying that **serving ads is disabled** because I reached the 10$ threshold and I need to confirm my billing address.

1. However, I did not receive any post mail from Google.
2. Also, there is no card on the Home page where I can enter a PIN.
3. On my "Account information" page, there is no button called Resend PIN.

What should I do in this case?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to your question? I am having the same issue now.

Comment: I am looking for an answer too. Please  help